# Creating a loop using a list of values with Excel Macro/VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a list of values in cells A1:A10.

I want to create a macro so that cell B1 will first contain the first value in the list, then the second value replace it, then the third, and so on. Once the entire list is run through, it should loop back to the first value again. The same sequence/order should run throughout.

If it impacts any of the code, I will likely end up using a button to run this code, so that each time the button is pressed the next item on the list takes over cell B1.

Is there any code that can be entered to help start the loop? When I run a macro all I get the same value repeatedly.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Here is one of my more recent attempts:

```
Sub macro1()
  Dim LR As Long, i As Long
  With ActiveSheet
    LR = .Range("A1" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LR
      .Range("A" & i).Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("B1")
    Next i
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like a plan, give it a go.

Comment: Spend some time here first and come back with an improved question https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: _Is there any code that can be entered to help start the loop?_  Maybe a worksheet event like `Worksheet_Change`?  Hard to tell if that's what you're after though - have a look at [MCVE].

Comment: Can't see a reference to B1 in your code? What do you want to happen when these values are copied?

Comment: Should be `LR = .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: Are you replacing B1:B10 or just B1 repeatedly? And why does your code assign repeatedly to F3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description and provided code, it seems like this is what you're looking for:

```
Sub btnNext_Click()

    Const sListStartAddr As String = "A1"   'This is the cell address where your list of values to be cycled through starts
    Const sOutputAddr As String = "F3"      'This is the cell address where the current value of the "loop" will be output

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rList As Range
    Dim rUpdateCell As Range
    Dim rFound As Range

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rList = ws.Range(sListStartAddr, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, ws.Range(sListStartAddr).Column).End(xlUp))
    Set rUpdateCell = ws.Range(sOutputAddr)

    If Len(Trim(rUpdateCell.Value)) = 0 Then
        'Update Cell is blank, put first value from list
        rUpdateCell.Value = rList.Cells(1).Value
    Else
        Set rFound = rList.Find(rUpdateCell.Value, rList.Cells(rList.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
        If rFound Is Nothing Then
            'Update Cell isn't blank, but its value isn't in the list, replace with first value from list
            rUpdateCell.Value = rList.Cells(1).Value
        Else
            If rFound.Row = rList.Row + rList.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                'Update Cell isn't blank and its value is in the list, but it's the last item in the list, replace with first value from list
                rUpdateCell.Value = rList.Cells(1).Value
            Else
                'Update Cell isn't blank, its value is in the list, and it's not the last item in the list, proceed to next value in the list
                rUpdateCell.Value = rFound.Offset(1).Value
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```